# Revisions should be visible on Area51

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list, area-51, example-questions

Example question and proposal revisions should be visible on Area51 so one can see how the questions and proposals have been refined over time.

While one could post 10 questions that split hairs to find the threshold of a particular aspect of a site's charter, it seems that a better technique would be to post a question, see if the response is overwhelmingly in one direction or the other (on or off topic) and refine the question to move it more towards the center.  It seems the questions which will best define the site will actually have a lot of both positive and negative votes, but still tend toward one side.

Further, it would be nice to have fewer questions that really straddle the line than hundreds of questions that merely come close to it.  I suspect this is best done by changing existing questions, rather than asking new questions.

However, people may need to see the evolution of a question to understand why previous voters voted the way they did.

- In addition to the Link, Edit, etc functions below each proposal and question, a *"Edited x times<sup>1</sup>, last was y minutes/hours/days ago"* link needs to be provided.

<sup>1<sub>In addition to the last time it was edited, this method might be easier if people could see how many times an example question was edited.</sub></sup>

Comment: Can't believe this isn't available.  It's very annoying to see that someone has edited my proposal but I have no way to find out what they changed.